# Get the value/solution from an comparison in an if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a comparison in my `if` statement to check if the id's are identical, but I want to detect the `B` element who has the same id as the `A` element and give him a class. You can see the problem in this script:

```js
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
  var a = jQuery('.a').attr('id')
  var b = jQuery('.b').attr('id')

  if (a === b) {

    // "jQuery(this)" should be the detectet B-element, which has the same "id" as A
    // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    jQuery(this).css("background", "red");

    // But it detects the button as "jQuery(this)"

  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

```css
.a,
.b,
.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
<div class="a" id="block">A</div>
<div class="b" id="block">B</div>
<div class="c" id="notblock">C</div>
```

**Thanks for helping!**

Comment: ID should be unique you have same ID of block

Comment: Yeah the class name can be common not the DOM ID.

Comment: Your entire logic is flawed as you should never have two elements with the same `id` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the optimised code that you can have a look at. Instead of ID, you can use `data` attributes:

```js
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
  var a = jQuery('.a').data('check');
  var $belement = jQuery('.b');
  var b = $belement.data('check');

  if (a === b) {
    $belement.addClass("active").css("background", "red");
  }
});
```

```css
.a,
.b,
.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
<div class="a" id="block-a" data-check="block">A</div>
<div class="b" id="block-b" data-check="block">B</div>
<div class="c" id="notblock" data-check="notblock">C</div>
```

Ideally, DOM should never have same IDs. **IDs are unique**, classes can be same. And hence, your entire logic or question is kinda incorrect. You should rather compare some value or other attributes, but never IDs. **IDs can't be compared** as they are supposed to unique.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. The solution was so simple. I knew that ID-shitstorm was coming ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    var a = jQuery('.a').attr('id')
    var b = jQuery('.b').attr('id')
    if (a === b ) {
          // "jQuery(this)" should be the detectet B-element, which has the same "id" as A
          // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
          jQuery('.b').addClass("active");
          jQuery('.b').css("background", "red");
          // But it detects the button as "jQuery(this)"
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
});
```

Add the class to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you need to get b element jquery object, here jQuery(this) is the button you clicked

```js
jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    var a = jQuery('.a').attr('id');
    var $belement = jQuery('.b');
    var b = $belement.attr('id')

    if (a === b ) {
          
          // "jQuery(this)" should be the detectet B-element, which has the same "id" as A
          // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
          $belement.addClass("active");
          $belement.css("background", "red");
          
          // But it detects the button as "jQuery(this)"

    }
    else {
      return;
    }
});
```

```css
.a, .b, .c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
<div class="a" id="block">A</div>
<div class="b" id="block">B</div>
<div class="c" id="notblock">C</div>
```